# Classify single image based on trained tensorflow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, classification, conv-neural-network

I'm using convolutional neural networks to classify images in 3 labels. I did all the training and test and got an accuracy of 60%. Then, I saved this model and I want to load a single image and classify it into one of those labels. The code I'm using:

```
X_new = process_data() # That's my input image after some processing
pred = convolutional_neural_network(x) # That's my CNN

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Here I restore the trained model
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('modelo.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, 'modelo')
    print('Model loaded')

    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

    # Here I'm trying to predict the label of my image
    c = sess.run(pred, feed_dict={x: X_new})

    print(c)
```

When I print **c**, it returns me something like this:

```
[[ 1.5495030e+07 -2.3345528e+08 -1.5847101e+08]]
```

But I couldn't find out what that means and what I should do with it.
Anyway, what I'm trying to do is to get a percentage of how much an image belongs to some label. If anyone can help me with that, I will be so grateful! I'm new to tensorflow and I'm having difficulties.

Thank you so much!

**EDIT:**

The convolutional_neural_network method:

```
def convolutional_neural_network(x):
    weights = {'W_conv1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 3, 1, 32])), 
               'W_conv2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 3, 32, 64])),
               'W_fc': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([54080, 1024])), 
               'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024, n_classes]))}

    biases = {'b_conv1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32])),
              'b_conv2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64])),
              'b_fc': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1024])),
              'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))}

    x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, IMG_PX_SIZE, IMG_PX_SIZE, HM_SLICES, 1])

    conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv3d(x, weights['W_conv1']) + biases['b_conv1'])
    conv1 = maxpool3d(conv1)

    conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv3d(conv1, weights['W_conv2']) + biases['b_conv2'])
    conv2 = maxpool3d(conv2)

    fc = tf.reshape(conv2, [-1, 54080])
    fc = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(fc, weights['W_fc']) + biases['b_fc'])
    fc = tf.nn.dropout(fc, keep_rate)

    output = tf.matmul(fc, weights['out']) + biases['out']

    return output
```

Comment: the answer to this question would depend heavily on what is in convolutional_neural_network()

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the help, I added the code of my convolutional network!

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the type of activation layer used at the last layer of the model. I am assuming softmax as there are 3 labels to predict. Based on the values, I think the network was not able to predict the label with high certainty hence the low values. If you just want to know the label of the image use argmax function of numpy library like this

```
import numpy as np
c=np.argmax(c)
print(c)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you seem to just have a linear regression output layer (or logits layer), so it is hard to interpret the outputs. We would also need to see your loss function to understand the outputs you are seeing.

However, for classification into one of 3 labels you would normally want to terminate your network with a softmax layer, then the outputs will be interpretable as a probabilities for each label (multiply by 100 if you need percentages).

```
   probabilities = tf.nn.softmax(output)
```

You would still train your classifier using your output/logits layer with softmax cross entropy loss with your grounth-truth 'y' values.

```
losses = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=output, labels=y)
```